# Can I just ask in the loop(foreach) condition

Tags: c#, foreach, c#-2.0

You can create the same design but without the condition (if) ?

```
foreach (var item in ListItems)
{
    if(item.IsChecked)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

for example(not worked example):

```
foreach (var item in ListItems(=>IsCheked))
{
    //only IsChecked
}
```

c#-2.0 - not use linq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# 3 and Framework 3.5:

```
foreach(var item in ListItems.Where(x => x.IsChecked))
```

C# 2 , Framework 2.0 (assuming ListItems is a List)

```
foreach(<type> item in ListItems.FindAll(delegate(x) { return x.IsChecked; }))
```

C# 3, Framework 2.0 (if you're using visual studio 2008 or later but targeting 2.0 framework)
   The lambda syntax and `var` keyword can be compiled, but there is no System.LINQ library to refer to.

```
foreach(var item in ListItems.FindAll(x => x.IsChecked))
```

Comment: just trying to clear up a bit of confusion in the comments on the other answer.

Comment: If using C#3, you can always redefine Where: `public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> condition) { foreach (T item in source) if (condition(item)) yield return item; }`

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
foreach (var item in ListItems.Where(i => i.IsChecked)) {
    /// ...
}
```

Comment: Question is tagged c#-2.0.  Linq and Lambdas didn't get introduced until 3.5

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that. The question did use the `var` keyword though!

Comment: @Kyle Trauberman, what? I just checked my project is set to 2.0